# AttributeError: 'version_info' object has no attribute '__version__' when trying to load Yolo Model Weights

Tags: python, package-management, pip

*I have been referred to this platform from Stack Overflow for this question.*

I am trying to follow the [How to Build Object Detection APIs Using TensorFlow and Flask](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UqmgHKdntU) video (on YouTube).

I cloned the GitHub repository, and then I downloaded the weight files. 
I also created a virtual environment with `python 3.6.0` (because Python 3.9.2 was giving error due to incompatibility with TensorFlow version 2.2, which was in the `requirements.txt` file).

However, when I tried to load the weights with the following command,

```
python load_weights.py
```

I am getting this error,

```
File "load_weights.py", line 4, in <module>
    from yolov3_tf2.models import YoloV3, YoloV3Tiny

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "load_weights.py", line 4, in <module>
    from yolov3_tf2.models import YoloV3, YoloV3Tiny
  File "E:\Example4\Object-Detection-API\yolov3_tf2\models.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .utils import broadcast_iou
  File "E:\Example4\Object-Detection-API\yolov3_tf2\utils.py", line 5, in <module>
    from seaborn import color_palette
  File "E:\Example4\Object-Detection-API\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .rcmod import *  # noqa: F401,F403
  File "E:\Example4\Object-Detection-API\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py", line 5, in <module>
    import matplotlib as mpl
  File "E:\Example4\Object-Detection-API\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "E:\Example4\Object-Detection-API\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 28, in <module>
    from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
  File "E:\Example4\Object-Detection-API\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\fontconfig_pattern.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pyparsing import (Literal, ZeroOrMore, Optional, Regex, StringEnd,
  File "E:\Example4\Object-Detection-API\venv\lib\site-packages\pyparsing\__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    __version__ = __version_info__.__version__
AttributeError: 'version_info' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

As usual, the important bit is at the end;
note that the last line is the error shown in the title. 
I tried to find this on Stack Overflow and other places on the web
(searching with Google) but could not find anything that worked for me.

[An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69964466/3960947#70061207) by encubos to [unknown version in python library pyparsing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69964466/3960947)
on Stack Overflow told me to change the `pyparsing` library.

I checked the pyparsing version using the command `pip show pyparsing`,
which displayed the following results,

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ensorflow (e:\hassan\example4\object-detection-api\venv\lib\site-packages)
Name: pyparsing
Version: 3.0.7
Summary: Python parsing module
Home-page: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/
Author: Paul McGuire
Author-email: ptmcg.gm+pyparsing@gmail.com
License: MIT License
Location: e:\example4\object-detection-api\venv\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: matplotlib
```

After which I tried to install the pyparsing version 3.0.7 using the command

```
pip install pyparsing==3.0.7
```

However, I got this message,

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing==3.0.7 in e:\example4\object-detection-api\venv\lib\site-packages (3.0.7)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'E:\Example4\Object-Detection-API\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

*I also tried to uninstall the pyparsing and again install the specified version, but the problem still persisted.*

Another solution advised me to also install the `tensorflow-gpu`
which was given on the GitHub repository,

```
pip install -r requirements-gpu.txt
```

I tried this; however, this also did not work.  I also tried to uninstall and install TensorFlow again, but again the same error persisted.

I also tried to upgrade my pip by using this,

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

This showed me the message that,

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in e:\hassan\semester 8\research\example4\object-detection-api\venv\lib\site-packages (21.3.1)
```

However, at the end, it still said that new version is available
(but it wouldn't install it, I don't know for what reason).

```
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'E:\Example4\Object-Detection-API\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

How can I solve this `version` error?

Comment: (1) Can you explain the “invalid distribution -ensorflow” message? It makes me wonder whether “tensorflow” was misspelled or formatted incorrectly somewhere. I suggest that you try to resolve that.  (2) The Stack Overflow people are interesting. They answer questions that belong here, on Super User, but then they throw us a question that’s well within their scope.  (3) You should have included [a link to your question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71095302/3960947). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) One of the comments on [your question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71095302/3960947) says “The most common problem is trying to install to a different Python than the one being used to run the code.”  You mention “python 3.6.0”, but what have you done to clarify whether this is the problem, and resolve it?  (5) Are you sure that it makes sense to install the version of pyparsing that you already have?